# Problem in getting data from form in flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, request

I am basically creating a flask web app which takes username from user and gets his /her codeforces data I am having a problem in extracting the email-id
from the form. I am getting the username but not the email-id.They are both in one form tag in the html file.

Error in browser:
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'email-id'

```
<form method="POST">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="label">Username:</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter Codeforces username" name="username" value="{{user.handle}}"></input>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="has-text-centered">
                            <input class="button is-link" name="get-info" type="submit" value="Get Info">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="label">EMail id:</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter mail id" name="email-id" value="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="has-text-centered">
                            <input class="button is-link" name="get-mail" type="submit" value="Get Mail">
                        </div>
                    </form>


@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email_id = request.form['email-id']
        print(email_id)
        print(username)
```

Comment: Add your error here.

Comment: Add the html form part too. Maybe it does not have `email-id` field

Comment: I have added the div present in html file

Comment: Is it inside the form

Comment: Yes it is inside the form

Comment: Can't reproduce ; Works Fine

Comment: Should i post the whole code i cant seem to find the error.@SmartManoj

Comment: Did you edit code after running

Comment: No its the code that i ran